# About Fancybox and PHP Mysql Adding <br /> or new line in the title

Tags: php, mysql, html, fancybox

is there a way to to add `<br />` in the title??

cause i want to add something from another table data..

here's my code

```
 title="'.$row['product_name'].'" >' ...
```

for example
product_name is "Ben What"
product_desc is "Yeah Come at me"

i want to add some description in the title.. i don't want it to be connected in the title
i want to add break line but somehow it won't work.

the output should be

```
Ben What 
Yeah Come at me
```

not

```
Ben What Yeah Come at me
```

Thank you! i tried alot but it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're talking about the `title` attribute in an HTML tag.

HTML attributes attributes can not contain HTML themselves.

*Some* browsers let you put newlines in there using HTML entities, but you should not do this because of spotty support.

---

Your best best is going to be [using the `titleFormat` callback](http://fancybox.net/api) that Fancybox describes to perform some variety of transformation on the `title` attribute.

Comment: I think he's referring to the title in Fancybox, which is a title attribute on an `<img>` tag, IIRC.

Comment: You still can't put HTML in an attribute without some heavy duty escaping, which I'm not sure that Fancybox is going to be smart enough to undo on it's own.

Comment: i'm talking about the title in fancybox is there a possibility that i can use the <br /> in the title??

Comment: As I described in my answer, you can't just put a `br` tag in the title, things don't work that way.  You *can* use the `titleFormat` callback to provide a function to format titles in whatever way you want, including changing something that is not HTML into HTML.  Unfortunately I know nothing about Fancybox other than what I discovered in Google.  You will need to read their documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

i was having this problem too, so this is my solution, in the default configuration of fancybox change:

```
        $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });
```

To this one:

```
        $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">' + title + '</span>';
            }
        });
```

This way you can use HTML in fancybox title attribute:

```
<a rel="example_group" href="./example/9_b.jpg" title="Lorem <br/> ipsum dolor sit amet"><img alt="" src="./example/9_s.jpg" /></a>
```

Note the 
 inside of the title attribute.

This is the configuration that you can do with fancybox as @Charles talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `<br/>` you can use `<p>blah blah</p>`, this way i fixed my problem.

Comment: Unfortunatelly i don't have any idea how hide this syntax in preview when i hover mouse over img and i see `blah blah <p>blah</p>`